# How to make UICollectionView cells movable?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uicollectionview

I want to make additional categories in my UICollectionView, just like here 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJcpr.png

Is it possible to make using UICollectionView? How can we insert the additional view between cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you can implement the callout views (that appear for a selected cell) as section footers. In order to achieve that, you create a section for every row in the collection view. Then, when a cell is selected, you expand the footer that belongs to that row (section). There's a [tutorial](https://nrj.io/stretchy-uicollectionview-headers/) explaining how to expand headers (footers should be similar) animated utilizing a custom collection view layout.